# Google Scripts returning null on htttp.post() and http.get()

Tags: flutter, google-apps-script, http-get

From my Flutter app I had been making http requests to google sheet to put items and get items. [ initially had 4 variables] Everything was working pretty okay but now I wanted to add 3 more variables and when I request .get() its returning values of new added variables as a "null" and when I request .put() its still only getting values of old variables.
(previous variables were : date, name, product, quantity)

```
function doPost(request){
 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1AVouGZs3U2I4xM941sKWqgfJzyiUgP8-1lTI4gTX4tg");
  var result = {"status": "SUCCESS"};
  
 try{
    // Get all Parameters
    var date = request.parameter.date;
    var name = request.parameter.name;
    var product = request.parameter.product;
    var quantity = request.parameter.quantity;
   var discount = request.parameter.discount;
   var price = request.parameter.price;
   var delivery = request.parameter.delivery;
    // Append data on Google Sheet
  var rowData =  sheet.appendRow([date, name, product, quantity, discount,price, delivery]);

  }catch(exc){
   
    result = {"status": "FAILED", "message": exc};
  }

  // Return result
  return ContentService
  .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result))
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);

  
}

function doGet(request){
 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1AVouGZs3U2I4xM941sKWqgfJzyiUgP8-1lTI4gTX4tg");

  // Get all values in active sheet
  var values = sheet.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  var data = [];

  // Iterate values in descending order 
  for (var i = values.length; i >= 0; i--) {

    // Get each row
    var row = values[i];

    // Create object
    var order = {};

    order['date'] = row[0];
    order['name'] = row[1];
    order['product'] = row[2];
    order['quantity'] = row[3];
    order['dicount'] = row[4];
    order['price'] = row[5];
    order ['delivery'] = row [6];

    // Push each row object in data
    data.push(order);
  }

  // Return result
  return ContentService
  .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(data))
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

Codes from Flutter below (feedbackForm is a data class which stores all the data)

```
void submitForm(
  FeedbackForm feedbackForm, void Function(String) callback) async {
try {
  await http.post(URL, body: feedbackForm.toJson()).then((response) async {
    if (response.statusCode == 302) {
      var url = response.headers['location'];
      await http.get(url).then((response) {
        callback(convert.jsonDecode(response.body)['status']);
      });
    } else {
      callback(convert.jsonDecode(response.body)['status']);
    }
  });
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
  }

Future<List<FeedbackForm>> getFeedbackList() async {
    return await http.get(URL).then((response) {
      var jsonFeedback = convert.jsonDecode(response.body) as List;
      return jsonFeedback.map((json) => FeedbackForm.fromJson(json)).toList();
    });
    }
```

in form.dart I have :

```
    class FeedbackForm {
  String date;
  String name;
  String product;
  String quantity;
String discount;
String price;
String delivery;
String payment ;
  FeedbackForm(this.date, this.name, this.product, this.quantity, this.discount, this.price, this.delivery);

  factory FeedbackForm.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return FeedbackForm(
        "${json['date']}",
        "${json['name']}",
        "${json['product']}",
        "${json['quantity']}",
      "${json['discount']},",
        "${json['price']},",
        "${json['delivery']},");
  }

  // Method to make GET parameters.
  Map toJson() => {
        'date': date,
        'name': name,
        'product': product,
        'quantity': quantity,
    'discount' : discount,
    'price' : price,
    'delivery' : delivery,
      };
}
```

I double checked everything in flutter, I guess something is wrong with Google Script code. Any ideas?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour, data is getting retrieved and appended correctly. Can you show the code on the Flutter side? Also, not sure if this will fix the issue, but you wrote `dicount` instead of `discount` in the `doGet` function, and `values[i]` won't exist when `i == values.length`: you should change that to `for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {`.

Comment: I made the corrections you mention. No effect. still the same

Comment: @lamblichus Which part of flutter code you need? (its a lot of code to share) Part where I wrap the data to json? or where I make the http request?

Comment: Making the request and everything related to how you're handling the data.

Comment: Also, about `I made the corrections you mention. No effect. still the same`: `var row = values[i];` should have given you an error if you had `for (var i = values.length; i >= 0; i--) {`, since `values[values.length]` cannot ever exist. That makes me think that you are not using the code you shared. So the question would be: **are you publishing a new version of the code as web app after making changes?**